# Insert an empty row at a specific index and shift its values down dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, row

so for example I have this dataframe:

|  | onset | length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.215 | 1.3 |
| 2 | 23.107 | 1.3 |
| 3 | 41.815 | 1.3 |
| 4 | 61.606 | 1.3 |
| 5 | Nan | Nan |

and want to change it to this :

|  | onset | length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.215 | 1.3 |
| 2 | Nan | Nan |
| 3 | 23.107 | 1.3 |
| 4 | 41.815 | 1.3 |
| 5 | 61.606 | 1.3 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please research existing posts on this site before posting your question.  Searching for "pandas insert blank row at specific index" brings up several hits. Duplicate questions are subject to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack appends if necessary.

```
i = 2 # your target index

head = df[:i]
tail = df[i:]

inserted = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(df.columns)], columns=df.columns)

result = head.append(inserted, ignore_index=True)
result = result.append(tail, ignore_index=True)

print(result)
```